# Retrieve a query parameter within ui-router state controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So for instance I might have a stage as described:

```
.state('room', {
    url: "/room/:id",
    templateUrl: "app/views/room.html",
    controller: 'roomsCtrl'

})
```

And then a controller as defined:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('roomsCtrl', ['$scope','Room', function ($scope,Room) {
        $scope.rooms = Room.get({id: 1}, function(item) {

        });
        console.log($scope);



    }]);
```

In this instance Room is a service object that has been hooked up to a restful api. I would like to test to see if id is present within the controller and pass that to the id parameter "Room.get({id: 1}" if it exists otherwise pass nothing.

How would one retrieve the parameter id which would be present within the url?

In my case it shows up like: /#/room/1

Here is an example of some html from my view with a link that will key up to the id:

```
<a ui-sref="room({ id: '1' })">
    {{room.name}}
</a>
```

Comment: Checkout $location service on Angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: Will do, working on another project will finish that and try this. The first part didn't work. I think because of conflicts with the ui-router

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[$stateParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha)** if you are using  `$stateProvider`

`$stateParams` is an angular service which allows you to retrieve the current set of state parameters.

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('roomsCtrl', ['$scope','Room','$stateParams' function ($scope,Room, $stateParams) {

       var id = $stateParams.id;
       :
    }]);
```

If you are using **[$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider)** then use **[$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24routeParams)**

Also Try

```
var id = $routeParams.id;
```